# sum and average of rows from list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I'm interested to sum each row from list of data frames. That is first row needs to be summed across all the data frame in the list. Likewise, second and such.
Once the addition is complete, I'd like to take the average by the number of data frames in the list. I do it with the following code (tedious)

```
sample_list<-list(data.frame(x=c(1:5)),data.frame(x=c(6:10)), data.frame(x=c(11:15)) ) ## sample data frame's list

sum_per_person<-matrix(nrow=nrow(sample_list[[1]]),ncol=1) ## create a matrix to store sum of each row from the list of data frames.

number_indi=nrow(sample_list[[1]]) ## number of rows are same in each data frame within the list

iterate_person=1 ## set counter 

while(iterate_person<=number_indi){ ## do a while loop

sum_temp=0 ## set to zero
for(x in 1:length(sample_list)){
## iterate over the sample list
sum_temp<-sum_temp+(sample_list[[x]])[iterate_person,]

} ## iteration ends for the list

sum_per_person[iterate_person,1]<-sum_temp
iterate_person<-iterate_person+1 ## increment 
} ## for loop ends 

## take average
sum_per_person<-sum_per_person/length(sample_list) ## final result
```

Is there a way I can accomplish this in non-complicated way via lapply, apply?

Comment: Not sure, maybe it could be done with a lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `while` loop, an option in `R` would be to get the sum of corresponding elements of `list` with `Reduce` and divide by the `length` of the 'sample_list'

```
Reduce(`+`, sample_list)/length(sample_list)
#  x
#1  6
#2  7
#3  8
#4  9
#5 10
```

---

Or a concise approach is `rowMeans` after converting it to a single data.frame

```
rowMeans(do.call(cbind, sample_list))
```

Comment: thank you. Didn't know about `Reduce`. Second approach is quite fancy and terse. :)